# serenity-js- How to debug code in the project

Tags: cucumber, serenity-js

Is there any particular settings that has to be done in intellij or Visual studio code that has to be made to debug serenity-js projects

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Serenity/JS with Protractor you can debug your test scenario using [similar techniques](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md) as with the regular Protractor scripts. If you're using IntelliJ you might also want to look into using the ["Protractor run configuration"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/run-debug-configuration-protractor.html).

If you're using Serenity/JS directly with Mocha, you can use the ["Mocha run configuration"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-mocha.html) in IntelliJ.

Hope that [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)!

Jan